# Multiple boxplots with predefined statistics using lattice-like graphs in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, boxplot

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
 VegType    87MIN   87MAX   87Q25   87Q50   87Q75   96MIN   96MAX   96Q25   96Q50     96Q75 00MIN   00MAX   00Q25   00Q50   00Q75
 1          0.02    0.32    0.11    0.12    0.13    0.02    0.26    0.08    0.09    0.10    0.02    0.28    0.10    0.11    0.12
 2          0.02    0.45    0.12    0.13    0.13    0.02    0.20    0.09    0.10    0.11    0.02    0.26    0.11    0.12    0.12
 3          0.02    0.29    0.13    0.14    0.14    0.02    0.27    0.11    0.11    0.12    0.02    0.26    0.12    0.13    0.13
 4          0.02    0.41    0.13    0.13    0.14    0.02    0.58    0.10    0.11    0.12    0.02    0.34    0.12    0.13    0.13
 5          0.02    0.42    0.12    0.13    0.14    0.02    0.46    0.10    0.11    0.11    0.02    0.28    0.12    0.12    0.13
 6          0.02    0.32    0.13    0.14    0.14    0.02    0.52    0.12    0.12    0.13    0.02    0.29    0.13    0.14    0.14
 7          0.02    0.55    0.12    0.13    0.14    0.02    0.24    0.10    0.11    0.11    0.02    0.37    0.12    0.12    0.13
 8          0.02    0.55    0.12    0.13    0.14    0.02    0.19    0.10    0.11    0.12    0.02    0.22    0.11    0.12    0.13
```

In reality I have 26 variables and 5 years (87,96 and 00 in the column names are years). In an ideal world I would like to have a lattice-like graph with 26 plots, one per variable, with each plot containing 5 boxes, i.e. one per year. I understand that it is not possible to do this is lattice because lattice won't accept predefined statistics. Is there a fairly unpainful way to do this in R with predefined stats? I have used `bxp` for simple boxplots plotting all the variables for one year in a single plot e.g.

```
Yr01 = read.csv('dat.csv',header=T)
dat01=t(Yr01[,c("01Min","01Q25","01Mean","01Q75","01Max")])
bxp(list(stats=dat01, n=rep(26, ncol(dat01))),ylim=c(0.07,0.2))
```

but I don't know how to go from there to what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done, at least using `ggplot2`, but you'll have to `reshape` your data quite a bit. And you **really** have to have a data where the quantiles actually make sense!! Your quantile values are all messed up! For example, `Var1` has `01Max = 0.26` and `01Q75 = .67`!!

First, I'll recreate a valid data:

```
n  <- c("01Min", "01Max", "01Med", "01Q25", "01Q75", "02Min", 
                            "02Max", "02Med", "02Q25", "02Q75")
v1 <- c(0.03,  0.76,  0.41,  0.13,  0.67,  0.10,  0.43,  0.27,  0.2,   0.33)
v2 <- c(0.03,  0.28,  0.14,  0.08,  0.20,  0.02,  0.77,  0.13,  0.06, 0.44)

df <- data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)
df <- as.data.frame(t(df))
names(df) <- n
df <- cbind(var=c("v1","v2"), df)
> df

#    var 01Min 01Max 01Med 01Q25 01Q75 02Min 02Max 02Med 02Q25 02Q75
# v1  v1  0.03  0.76  0.41  0.13  0.67  0.10  0.43  0.27  0.20  0.33
# v2  v2  0.03  0.28  0.14  0.08  0.20  0.02  0.77  0.13  0.06  0.44
```

Next, we'll reshape the data:

```
require(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id="var")
# look for a bunch of numbers from the start of the string and capture it
# in the first variable: () captures the pattern. And replace it with the 
# captured pattern with the variable "\\1"
df.m$year <- gsub("^([0-9]+)(.*$)", "\\1", df.m$variable)

# the same but instead refer to the captured pattern in the second 
# paranthesis using "\\2"
df.m$quan <- gsub("^([0-9]+)(.*)$", "\\2", df.m$variable)
df.f <- dcast(df.m, var+year ~ quan, value.var="value")
```

To get to this format:

```
> df.f

#   var year  Max  Med  Min  Q25  Q75
# 1  v1   01 0.76 0.41 0.03 0.13 0.67
# 2  v1   02 0.43 0.27 0.10 0.20 0.33
# 3  v2   01 0.28 0.14 0.03 0.08 0.20
# 4  v2   02 0.77 0.13 0.02 0.06 0.44
```

Now, we can plot by directly providing the quantile values to corresponding parameters using the corresponding `column names` as follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
p <- ggplot(df.f, aes(x=var, ymin=`Min`, lower=`Q25`, middle=`Med`, 
                           upper=`Q75`, ymax=`Max`)) 
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=year), stat="identity") 
p
```

[image: ggplot1]

```
# if you want facetting:
p + facet_wrap( ~ var, scales="free")
```

[image: ggplot2]

---

You can now accomplish your task of plotting all `years` for each `var` in a separate plot using a `lapply` with this code and `subsetting` as follows:

```
lapply(levels(df.f$var), function(x) {
    p <- ggplot(df.f[df.f$var == x, ], 
            aes(x=var, ymin=`Min`, lower=`Q25`, 
                middle=`Med`, upper=`Q75`, ymax=`Max`))
    p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=year), stat="identity")
    p
    ggsave(paste0(x, ".pdf"), last_plot())
})
```

**Edit:** Your data is different from the earlier data you provided in some aspects. So, here's the version of the code for your new data:

```
# change var to VegType everywhere
require(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id="VegType")

df.m$year <- gsub("^X([0-9]+)(.*$)", "\\1", df.m$variable) # pattern has a X
df.m$quan <- gsub("^X([0-9]+)(.*)$", "\\2", df.m$variable) # pattern has a X
df.f <- dcast(df.m, VegType+year ~ quan, value.var="value")
df.f$VegType <- factor(df.f$VegType) # convert integer to factor

require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
p <- ggplot(df.f, aes(x=VegType, ymin=`MIN`, lower=`Q25`, middle=`Q50`, 
                           upper=`Q75`, ymax=`MAX`)) 
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=year), stat="identity") 
p
```

You can facet/write as separate plots using same code as before.

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough answer! I'm stuck at the reshape stage, I suspect because, unlike in my example, my years aren't `01,02` etc but actually `87,96,00,06,09` so I guess the `gsub` code is not working as it would if my data had been as I had suggested. Also, I admit that I don't really understand what `^([0-9]+)(.*)$` is doing...

Comment: Bingo! The code works. One last question: writing `df <- cbind(var=c("v1","v2"), df)` is fine if I only have 2 rows but given that I have 26 I don't really want to write explicitly `"v1",...,"V26"`. Is there some sort of wild card I can use to say i want all var, eg. `df <- cbind(var=c("v*"), df)`?

Comment: No, I don't want to change the names of `VegType`. What I am wondering is, whether we call the VegType `1,2,3,...,8` or `v1,v2,v3...,v8`, is there a wild card I can use in the cbind command, in the first grey box of your answer, that would allow me to not have to write `df <- cbind(VegType=c("1","2","3",etc until "8"), df)` but something like `df <- cbind(VegType=c(1:8), df)`. Thanks.